# youtube api v3-ios: How do I allow user to report a youtube video as inappropriate?

Tags: ios, youtube-data-api

In YouTube v2, user can report a video as inappropriate through following way,

```
-(void)flagInappropriateVideo: (NSString*)inVideoId 
{

    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youtubeService];

    [service fetchEntryWithURL:videoEntryFetchURL completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataEntryBase *entry, NSError *error) {
        NSError *err = error;
        NSURL *complaintsLink = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo*)entry complaintsLink] URL];
        if(err || !entry || !complaintsLink)
        {
            if(!err)
                err = [NSError errorWithDomain: UNKNOWN_ERROR_DOMAIN code: UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE userInfo: nil]; 
        }
        else
        {
            GDataEntryYouTubeComplaint *complaint = [GDataEntryYouTubeComplaint complaintEntry];
            [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:complaint
                                     forFeedURL: complaintsLink
                                       delegate:self
                              didFinishSelector:@selector(complaintTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)complaintTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
      finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryBase *)entry
                  error:(NSError *)error 
{
    // handle completion
}
```

I did not find any equivalent classes and methods for **GDataEntryYouTubeVideo** and **complaintsLink** also the **GDataEntryYouTubeComplaint** to report a **complaintEntry** in YouTube V3.
I would like to know whether this is depreciated or is there any other way to do this? Please do help,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see them from [GDataObjectiveC client.](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Clients/YouTube/GDataEntryYouTubeComplaint.m?r=289)

Comment: GDataEntryYouTubeComplaint.m class is not there in youtube api v3.